# What does it mean "a man leaves his father and mother"?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-bereishit, children-parenting

Please help me understand the meaning of this phrase ([Gen 2.24](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.2?lang=bi&aliyot=0):

> עַל־כֵּן יַעֲזָב־אִישׁ אֶת־אָבִיו וְאֶת־אִמּוֹ וְדָבַק בְּאִשְׁתּוֹ וְהָיוּ לְבָשָׂר אֶחָד׃
>   Hence a man leaves his father and mother and clings to his wife so that they become one flesh.

As I don't see any source that a man should cling to his parents in the first place, the only possible connection that links kids to their parents is the commandment to honor them (inexistent with Gentiles), so I don't understand the meaning of leaving them.

So, besides the trivial and natural leaving the house, what is the meaning of "leaving his father and mother"?

Comment: Look at Onkelos and Ramban for explanations

Comment: I assume you’re looking for a pshat explanation, and not the Gemara which expounds each part of this passuk as excluding certain types of marital relations from being permissible to non-Jews?

Answer (score 1):

Rav Hirsch explains that this shows that a *man* is not complete until he marries and becomes a an independent being with a partner of his own. Until that occurs, he is part of the family unit and subject to the control of his parents.

> Therefore, because as long as man was alone it was not yet "good", and
>   because once the division had been made, it was no longer possible for
>   the man to fulfill his calling by himself, because his wife was to be
>   עזר כנגדו, without her he was only half a man, and only together with
>   her did he feel himself a whole man, therefore a man leaves his father
>   and his mother and attaches himself to a wife, and they become one
>   body.

Comment: Perhaps, implied in this answer, is the halachic notion that frequently where there is a conflict, such as Shalom Bayit vs. Kibud Av, he may be allowed / required to appease his wife first. If this is true, it would support this point.

Comment: @DanF I'd suggest you post it as a separate answer, nothing in R"H suggests that

Comment: I don't in the quote understand where he provides the reason for leaving the parents.

Comment: @AlBerko Your question doesn't seem to ask for the reason for doing it. Only what the phrasing means. This seems to answer it.

Comment: @AlBerko Rav Hirsch points out that until he is married he is not a complete man even staying with his parents. Thus, he must leave his parents and marry to become a *complete* human being.